# Move another mesh along a surface when animating

Tags: animation, snapping, path

I am trying to make an animated lock tumbler and the key pins should move along the contour of the key.  My goal is to move the pins up when the key passes underneath them by using some sort of snap to surface setting and constraining the motion of the pin to only the Z-axis.  I'd also like to set a minimum for the Z-axis so once they get to a certain minimum height they won't drop any lower (to simulate the pins resting at the bottom of the cylinder.  I have been doing a lot of searching for snap to surface and motion along a path but I'm not sure that I can use that during an animation.  Does anyone have advice on how to approach this?  I'm attaching an image of the key with the pins snapped to the part of the key I'd like it to track.

[image]

Comment: Read about drivers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way, it's not perfect, because of the limitations of the [*Clamp To*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/tracking/clamp_to.html) constraint.

1. Duplicate a central loop of your key, and *Header > Object Menu >*
   convert it to a curve. Extend the curve to tip-base level on both sides.
2. Place the origins of your tumbler-pins at their tips.
3. Assign them each a *Clamp To* constraint, targeted on the curve.

[image]

(It's sensible to get this constraint working on one tumbler to begin with, *after* settling the curve, making sure its scale is applied, etc.)

Because of the way the constraint interpolates the curve, there's some drift in the horizontal direction. You can eliminate this with another constraint on the tumbler: *Limit Location* to fix it in all axes apart from  up-and-down.

[image]

If the whole lot is to be parented to other parts for rigging, it might be better to do that first.

[image]

the curve remains editable to make small adjustments to the pin positions, if necessary. Excuse the grotty .gif

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I gave it a try, and I got the pins moving but I am getting some drift along the Y axis even with limit location Y set to 0.0-0.0 local on the pin mesh.  You don't seem to be having the same issue.. trying to figure out the difference. Including a link to the gif of my animation. [link](https://gfycat.com/clearcutvaluableibex)

Comment: Also adding a grab of the object constraints on the pin mesh. [link](https://gfycat.com/infinitesociablegiraffe)

Comment: I did convert it to a poly curve which simplified it and it didn't line up so well with the key, but it did reduce the drift significantly.  Then when I remapped it to the key contour the drift came back.  Do you happen to know where the limitations are documented so I can understand them better?  Hoping it will let me work around them a bit.  Thanks again for all of the info, accepted this as the best answer as it gets me 98% there.

Comment: @mord Aaah ! the limit location should come _after_ the clamp.. be superimposed on it. Hold back, You never know, someone might come up with a better way.

Comment: @mord The explanation of how the constraint works is in the manual page linked in the answer.

Comment: Actually, by using limit location and using global coordinates instead of local, and then setting the y value to the location of the pin I was able to stop the drift and it is working nicely.  Maybe a bit hacky but it's achieving the desired result. And I tried changing the order but it didn't affect it.  Thanks for pointing out the link, I did not notice it my first read through.

Comment: @mord.. yup, this is all a bit hacky.